# MySQL treats password in script as database

Tags: mysql, bash, command-line-arguments

I am new to Bash scripting. I want to create a script that logs in to MySQL for me:

```
PASSWORD="MyPassword"

sudo service mysql start

mysql -u root -p $PASSWORD
```

However, it throws an error telling me that my password (`$PASSWORD`) is not a database.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks and sorry if I am asking something RTFM or UTFM.

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man mysql`:

> If you use the short option form (-p), you cannot have a space between the option and the password.

So either

```
mysql -u root -p"$PASSWORD"
```

or

```
mysql -u root --password "$PASSWORD"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is insecure to use password on the command line.

From the [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-security-user.html) user guide:

> This is convenient but insecure. On some systems, your password becomes visible to system status programs such as ps that may be invoked by other users to display command lines.

I would suggest You to use the [mysql_config_editor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html) utility, to store your db credentials.

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=YOUR_LOGIN_PATH --host=YOUR_HOST --user=YOUR_DB_USER --password
```

Then it will ask for password interactively

After that you can connect to your db:

```
mysql --login-path=YOUR_LOGIN_PATH YOUR_DB
```

Example (set credentials):

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=root --host=localhost --user=root --password
```

Example (connect to db in your script):

```
mysql --login-path=root YOUR_DB
```